# HTTPSサイトでSecure属性を持たないCookieの取り扱いに関して

Tags: security, ssl, cookie

HTTPSのみを使用するウェブアプリケーションでは基本的にCookieへのSecure属性付与が推奨されると存じます。

その上で、HTTPを使用中にMITMによりCookieが窃取されるのは理解できますが、
HTTPS環境でも以下の様な罠リンクを踏ませる事でCookieの窃取が出来ると記載が有りました。

```html
<img src="http://www.sample.jp:443/" width="1" height="1";>
```

HTTPでのアクセスが出来ないウェブサイトの場合においても上記の手法でCookieを窃取する事が可能なのでしょうか？
もし可能であればどういった仕組みで攻撃を実現させているのでしょうか？

HTTPでアクセスした際にタイムアウトになるウェブサイトがあったとして、
そこに無理やりHTTPを指定してアクセスした際にCookieが送信されるとすれば、
サーバーからのレスポンスが無くてもクライアントがGET要求に付与したCookieが盗まれるという事でしょうか？

以上、知恵をお貸し頂ければ非常に助かります。

Comment: 正確な記述内容を知りたいと考えているのですが、その説明が為されている媒体を具体的に示すことはできるでしょうか。

Comment: いくつか参照元は御座いますが、具体的に記述されていたのは以下の情報源となります。https://blog.tokumaru.org/2013/09/cookie-manipulation-is-possible-even-on-ssl.html

Comment: そのページの見出し「Secure属性のないCookieを盗聴する」の最後で解説されていると思うのですが、その解説では理解できないということでしょうか？

Comment: 盗聴が可能な事と具体的な手法は理解で来たのですが、この罠ページを踏んだ際にクライアントとサーバー間でどういうやりとりがなされてCookieが窃取されるかの詳細を理解したいと考えております。何故この手法でCookieを窃取する事が可能なのかとも言い換えられます。
SSLページにリダイレクトされたりHTTPプロトコルでアクセス出来ない（非HSTS)Webサイトの場合でもこの手法は有効なのでしょうか？

Comment: 或いはHTTPプロトコルを明示する事でサーバの返答に関わらずクライアントに一方的にCookieを送らせて、中間者が盗聴する（サーバからのレスポンスは関係ない）という事でしょうか？そういうことなら理解が出来ます。
それなら単純にhttpsの部分をhttpに書き換えてアクセスさせるだけでも同じ事が成立するのかと推測しております。

Comment: クライアントからの最初のGETの時にCookieがサーバーに送信されるので、サーバーの応答は関係ありません。例えば、ネットワークを切断した状態でWebサイトにアクセスを試みると簡単に観察できると思います。

Comment: ご回答有難う御座いました。納得する事が出来ました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下の動画ではいかがでしょうか?

[TCP/IPを理解している人ほど間違いやすい 常時SSLでもCookieのSecure属性が必要な理由 - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXNOJE9kGK8)